# Multiple Inheritance in Python - TypeError "missing 1 required positional argument"

Tags: python, oop, typeerror, multiple-inheritance

I'm only really getting to grips with OOP and I have been looking at multiple inheritance. The problem I have, is when I instantiate the class `Hybrid`, which inherits from more than one class, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multi_inherit.py", line 44, in <module>
    hawk = Hybrid('hawk', 200, 650)
  File "multi_inherit.py", line 35, in __init__
    Archer.__init__(self, name, arrows)
  File "multi_inherit.py", line 13, in __init__
    super().__init__(name)
TypeError: Wizard.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'power'
```

The other classes work absolutely fine.

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def greet(self):
        return f"Welcome, {self.name.title()}."


class Archer(User):
    def __init__(self, name, arrows):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.arrows = arrows

    def shoot_arrow(self):
        self.arrows -= 1
        return "You shot an arrow!"

    def arrows_left(self):
        return f"You have {self.arrows} arrows remaining."


class Wizard(User):
    def __init__(self, name, power):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.power = power

    def cast_spell(self):
        return f"You cast a spell with a power of {self.power}"


class Hybrid(Archer, Wizard):
    def __init__(self, name, arrows, power):
        Archer.__init__(self, name, arrows)
        Wizard.__init__(self, name, power)

    def powerful(self):
        return "Hybrids are super powerful!"


merlin = Wizard('merlin', 1000)
robin = Archer('robin', 150)
hawk = Hybrid('hawk', 200, 650)

print(merlin.greet())
print(merlin.cast_spell())

print(robin.arrows_left())
print(robin.shoot_arrow())
print(robin.arrows_left())
```

Comment: You are trying to use `super` wiht multiple inheritance, then *every* class should be using `super`. Your classes have to be designed to support this from the ground up.  see: https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Comment: Multiple inheritance, use of `super()`, parameter lists that are different for each class - *pick any two*, all three simply do not get along.  The specific problem is that `super()` doesn't necessarily invoke the class you expect when there's a diamond in the inheritance graph - so you don't know what set of parameters to pass to it.  Explicitly naming the parent class in each inherited call may be the simplest fix here.

Comment: What's basically happening is that you call `Archer.__init__(self, name, arrows)` where `self` is a `Hybrid` object, then in `Archer.__init__`, you call `super().__init__(name)`. So the MRO of `Hybrid` is `[__main__.Hybrid, __main__.Archer, __main__.Wizard, __main__.User, object]`, so super knows it has a hybrid object, in the `Archer` class, so it proxies to the *next* class in the Hybrid MRO, i.e. `Wizard.__init__`, but you only passed a single argument, and the second positional argument is missing

Comment: Also, check out the great PyCon talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo which goes into a lot of details and builds up examples of how to use cooperative inheritance.

Comment: In the Archer and Wizard classes if you replace `super().__init__(name)` with `User.__init__(self, name)` it will fix your problem. I don't think this is the proper way of fixing it though; someone else will probably come along with a better answer.

Comment: @hostingutilities.com that is a perfectly valid approach, but in that case, you shouldn't be using `super` at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes as you have them now aren't great for use in multiple inheritance. When using multiple inheritance I prefer having constructors that agree on the same contract (use the same arguments) or no arguments at all. Here `powers` and `arrows` differ which makes calling each constructor awkward.

IMO A better way to design this class would be mixins. The mixins would have no constructors and depend on particular values being present in the classes which extend them.

Example Mixins:

```
class UserMixin:
    name: str

    def greet(self):
        return f"Welcome, {self.name.title()}."


class ArcherMixin(UserMixin):
    arrows: int

    def shoot_arrow(self):
        self.arrows -= 1
        return "You shot an arrow!"

    def arrows_left(self):
        return f"You have {self.arrows} arrows remaining."


class WizardMixin(UserMixin):
    power: int

    def cast_spell(self):
        return f"You cast a spell with a power of {self.power}"
```

Example Implementations:

```
class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class Archer(ArcherMixin):
    def __init__(self, name, arrows):
        self.name = name
        self.arrows = arrows


class Wizard(WizardMixin):
    def __init__(self, name, power):
        self.name = name
        self.power = power


class Hybrid(ArcherMixin, WizardMixin):
    def __init__(self, name, arrows, power):
        self.name = name
        self.arrows = arrows
        self.power = power

    def powerful(self):
        return "Hybrids are super powerful!"
```

Example usage:

```
merlin = Wizard('merlin', 1000)
robin = Archer('robin', 150)
hawk = Hybrid('hawk', 200, 650)

print(merlin.greet())
print(merlin.cast_spell())

print(robin.greet())
print(robin.arrows_left())
print(robin.shoot_arrow())
print(robin.arrows_left())

print(hawk.greet())
print(hawk.cast_spell())
print(hawk.arrows_left())
print(hawk.shoot_arrow())
print(hawk.arrows_left())
```

```
Welcome, Merlin.
You cast a spell with a power of 1000
Welcome, Robin.
You have 150 arrows remaining.
You shot an arrow!
You have 149 arrows remaining.
Welcome, Hawk.
You cast a spell with a power of 650
You have 200 arrows remaining.
You shot an arrow!
You have 199 arrows remaining.
```

Comment: Yep, the mixin pattern is usually much, much clearner.

Comment: I like this approach - Thank you! Now I've just got to get to grips with it so I can use this comfortably at will.

Comment: Been practising this and it's really sinking in - makes a lot of sense.

One question I have though is when stating the expected data type within the mixin classes, is there a reason why you use ':' as apposed to '='

For example when writing the UserMixin class you put 'name: str'

Comment: @ScottMButler `:` is used to apply a typehint annotation to the attribute name. It doesn't assign it to anything, which is what `=` is for. All it does is declare that there will be a attribute with that name/type available on concrete instances of the class.

Comment: @flakes Thanks so much for your help - greatly appreciated!